# When do you use the term "Dialect"?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english, vocabulary, variants

I've heard people use the terms:

> American English
>
> British English
>
> Australian English

I understand that all of them are English. However, sometimes when people use them, it's almost like they refer to them as different languages.

My question is:

Is it proper to call these dialects? Or do we use another term for classification like "variation"?

Are they technically classified as their own languages?

I originally thought of a dialect on a smaller scale. For example, Southerners in the U.S. use different words for some things and have different accents from people in the North (i.e. New Yorkers). So, I thought those would be dialects of American English. Then American, British, and Australian English would be dialects of English.

Comment: I'd say "dialect" always implies *[non-standard] deviation from an **original** [mainstream] language*, so if you were going to apply that to ***country-wide*** variants, you'd probably have to say American / Australian / Canadian / etc. English are all "dialects" of ***British*** English.

Comment: [*Australian English can be described as a **regional dialect** of English*.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB807GB807&ei=vPCHW4nZC4aWsAfh9qToDw&q=%22Australian+English+can+be+described+as+a+regional+dialect+of+English%22&oq=%22Australian+English+can+be+described+as+a+regional+dialect+of+English%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...26682.27895.0.28454.3.3.0.0.0.0.131.343.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.239...35i39k1.0.jsrsOTpNNZQ) But I kinda doubt most Australians would want their speech to be described as "dialectal", and Americans even less so.

Comment: There's a lot of flexibility in the term _dialect_ when you get down to it. As well as being 'super-dialects' (or something like that), AmE, BrE and AuE are also spelling and punctuation standards. _Dialect_ is often used to refer to (regional) language groupings that are primarily spoken and, as FumbleFingers says, that are notable in their deviance from a reference standard. (When speaking standard AmE, BrE or AuE, mutual intelligibility is effortless and the variation in punctuation and spelling is minor; I don't think  a serious case could be made for their being separate languages.)

Comment: This is a question that involves "schools of thought". I say varieties of English for AmE versus BrE, for example. Others say dialect. So be it. Personally, I don't use it. For me, each of those varieties probably has what can be qualified as dialects. However, just vocabulary is not enough for a dialect.

Comment: Words like "dialect," "variety," "register," etc are all nebulous with ill-defined boundaries. Plus usage differs between lay folk and (socio)linguists. I think a great answer to this question is possible

Comment: "A language is a dialect with an army and navy."

Comment: This question might be better received in **Linguistics Stack Exchange**.

Comment: @Fumble _Dialect_ may sometimes be somewhat condescending (implying ‘non-standard’, which again implies ‘inferior to the gold standard’), but it’s also frequently used neutrally. BrE is a group of dialects of English, as is AmE; AmE is not a dialect of BrE any more than Californian English is a dialect of New York English: they are paratactic, not hypotactic. Ultimately, there is no proper definition of _dialect_ **or** _language_, except to the extent that neither can exist without the other. A language is just a collection of dialects, and any dialect is a dialect _of_ a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is to note that English is a language that has its own dialects [variants] across the world; just like other languages, such as Mandarin, Arabic, French, Spanish, etc. The dialects of English can be British or American; Australian or South African; Indian or Pakistani . . . and the list goes on [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialects_of_the_English_language) on Wikipedia.

---

So here, you might want to ask:

> Are American, British, Australian and Indian English languages or dialects?

I would regard them as both, languages as well as dialects. It all depends on the situation wether you refer them as languages or dialects. Note that the dialects of English language have hundreds of sub-dialects of their own. English is a language, of which American and British are its dialects. But in terms of putting the British English aside from the American, then both can be regarded as languages (in such conditions). That's all because the duo languages have their own distinctive sub-dialects being spoken or written in a distinctive geographical region(s). For instance, British English is a kind of language spoken widely in the UK (also in the Republic of
Ireland as per the comment of **GEdgar** left beneath this answer), whereas the Scottish, the Welsh and the Northern Irish are the sub-dialects of it, in terms of linguistic, ethnic, regional, and social lines.

Similarly, American English is a kind of language that has its own sub-dialects. See how people living in southern parts of the USA speak American English differently as compared to the North-USA-English-speaking people.

**Besides, the Wikipedia site has something to say about the layout keyboards:**

> "The United Kingdom and Ireland use British layout keyboards, while Australia, South Africa, Canada, New Zealand and the U.S.A use American layout keyboards. In continental Europe English as a second language is nowadays sometimes even taught in American English, except perhaps in Scandinavia and the Netherlands." [Link](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English)

Comment: Just the Northern Irish? ;-)

Comment: @SConroy, yes it is Northern Irish. Look at the edited form now.

Comment: I'm sure it's not what you meant, but it sounds like you're implying Mandarin, Arabic, French, and Spanish don't have dialects, which is of course completely false.

Comment: @Ahmed, I was wondering why the Republic of Ireland (southern Ireland) was left out of the equation. The South doesn't belong to the UK, but the English language doesn't just stop at the border.

Comment: @AzorAhai, The OP's question has completely to do with the dialects of English, not of others.

Comment: It seems that part was listing dialects of "British English is a language spoken in the UK".  Which excludes the Republic of Ireland, of course.

Comment: @Ahmed I know. I meant that your parenthetical sounds like you're implying those languages don't have dialects. I would just suggest editing a little bit to clarify why you mention them

Comment: @AzorAhai, thanks for the correction. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: @SConroy, The upper comment of mine contains a typo, I purdon for that... Well, my comment is: "I just related the
languages of UK's sovereign
states. Southern Ireland is not
the part of UK. Correct me,
if I am saying wrong.
Corrections are welcomed." :-)

Comment: @Ahmed. It's kind of complex. The dialect doesn't just stop at a political border. That's all I was trying to say. In the link you provided, Ulster English (Northern Irish English) is listed under Irish English. Elsewhere you can read it's a variety of Hiberno-English influenced by Ulster Irish and the Scots language

Comment: @SConroy, I entirely agree with you here.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I've gained a lot of insight from the answer and the responses. You've given me a good kick-off point to look into the topic in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

The term "dialect" is appropriate in both cases.  It simply refers to the differing semantics of a particular language used by different groups of people.

The English language itself is just a vocabulary and some general grammatical rules.  Anything that conforms to that is technically English, but within those rules there is a lot of variation that can occur with pronunciation, inflection, word choice, slang, idiomatic expressions, etc.

*Dialect* specifically refers to differing semantics (the words that are chosen and the way they are used together). Differences in pronunciation or inflection by themselves are just *accents* and don't necessarily represent different dialects, although they are usually paired together.

Also remember that within British English, they have [Cockney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney), [Scottish English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_English), and [Welsh English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_English), which are all distinct dialects within the UK, just as Texans, New Yorkers, and [Cajuns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cajun_English) are dialectically distinct in the US.

The bottom line is that if the words being used are strange and different, but are otherwise mutually intelligible, they are simply different dialects of the same language.

Comment: [Welsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_language) is a "real" language, it is totally incomprehensible to the English. Likewise, Gaelic which *some* Irish people speak is another foreign language. Scotch is not a dialect. Scotsmen and women (or the Scottish) speak [Scots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language), and then there's the Scottish English (dialect). On the other hand, Texans and New Yorkers speak English and can understand one another perfectly well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA; I meant that when Scots and Welsh speak English, they do so with a distinct dialect; just as Cajuns do in Louisiana (many of whom speak French).

Comment: That is probably what you meant, but Celt, Gaelic, the Scots language and the Welsh language  are not dialects they are *unique* languages. Many of the people who live in these regions and nations do not know how to speak their region/country's national language, but almost everyone speaks English, and it is the official language of the UK. And by the way, Scotch is an acceptable adjective  for whisky, or a type of [candy/sweet](http://mentalfloss.com/article/66184/whats-difference-between-caramel-toffee-and-butterscotch), but the people of Scotland are not called "Scotch"

Comment: @Mari-LouA; I know :-) I wasn't trying to argue. I added some references to the Cockney, Scottish, and Welsh English Wikipedia pages to my answer to make it more clear (all of which use the word *dialect* BTW). Also good catch on the Scotch thing. That was a typo on my part.